# query to filter equality and difference values ​in the same column SQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Good afternoon, I have a table called codes, with two fields, ID and COD.

[image]

I must explain it in a simple way, because English is not my language, but I will try to make an analogy with SQL

```
select id from codes where cod = 'A' and cod = 'B'
```

should result : ids 1 and 2

and the next query that is that breaks my head

```
select id from codes where cod = 'B' and cod <> 'C'
```

should result: only id 2

Thank you very much as always

Comment: Which database are you using? You tagged mysql and sqlite.

Comment: If your're talking about the same column then 
`select id from codes where cod = 'B' and cod <> 'C'` 
should return the same result as 
`select id from codes where cod = 'B'`
as far as I know

Comment: I'm using SQLite

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery for != C`.

```
select id from codes where
    id not in (select id from codes where COD = 'C')
    and COD= 'B'
```